# In Mulesoft Dataweave 2.0 is there a way to test if an input string is XML or JSON format?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I have a String input to my API.  It can be either XML or JSON and I need to use the Read function on it to parse it into JSON.  What is the best way in MuleSoft 4 or Dataweave 2 to determine what format the String is in?

Maybe I could write a function  isXML(String inputString) or isJSON(String inputString).

As of now, I have something inelegant.  I'm trying to parse the input as XML and catching any parsing exceptions.  Inside the catch, I'll try to parse it as JSON.  I guess it's not a horrible solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/dw
var xml = "<test>XML</test>"
var json = '{"test":1, "test2": 2}'
var test = xml
---
// Try to read it as a JSON
dw::Runtime::try(() -> read(test,"application/json")) 
// Now try to read it as an XML
dw::Runtime::orElseTry(() -> read(test,"application/xml"))
// You have data that are neither of XML or JSON
dw::Runtime::orElse("Not XML or JSON")
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.  Thank you.